Error "GoException: no routes for location"
In simulator I am getting the error message when running the code below:

"GoException: no routes for location:
https://www.[testurl].com/jobs/testjobtitle

Please can you tell me why the simulator isn't displaying a blank page with the title "Jobs" as per this line?:
appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Jobs')),

This is the test code:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router));
}


final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'jobs/*',
          // builder: (_, state) => ItemDetails(path: state.path),
          builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Jobs')),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);


The error you're seeing indicates that the route isn't being matched as expected. By making the path explicit or adding better debugging or fallback routes, you should be able to resolve the issue and see why the simulator isn't displaying the Jobs page as intended.
final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'jobs/:jobTitle', // Explicitly match job titles
          builder: (_, state) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Jobs')),
            body: Center(child: Text('Job Title: ${state.params['jobTitle']}')),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

Hope this help

Thank you Vicky. I am getting a couple of errors: lib/main.dart:52:63: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
body: Center(child: Text('Job Title: ${state.path['jobTitle']}')),
^
lib/main.dart:52:62: Error: Operator '[]' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
body: Center(child: Text('Job Title: ${state.path['jobTitle']}')),

Could you please try ${state.params['jobTitle']} in place of ${state.path['jobTitle']},

Explanation : state.params: state.params is a Map<String, String> that contains the named parameters from your route. Here, you can safely access the 'jobTitle' parameter using state.params['jobTitle'].
state.path: state.path is a string representing the current path, and it doesn't store parameters in a map-like structure. That's why trying to use [] on state.path resulted in the error.

Thank you @vicky this gives:Error (Xcode): lib/main.dart:44:58: Error: The getter 'params' isn't defined for the class 'GoRouterState'.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.

There are couple of breaking changes in versions , which version you are using, kindly check the doc - https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog#700, and replace the params with appropriate name. Thanks

Kindly run, dart fix --apply, this will migrate your code to the required Version.

Thank you Vicky "dart fix --apply" did this trick :-)

Good to hear that,your issue has been resolved, kindly check the  doc - https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog#700
